# Anchor: Failed transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions

Tags: anchor, solana-program

When I try to run [this simple "hello world" example](https://github.com/buildspace/anchor-counter-program/blob/solution-decrement/tests/anchor-counter.ts), I get this error:

```
$ anchor test

Error: Function _ZN14solana_program4vote5state9VoteState11deserialize17h6501cbf018769324E Stack offset of 6344 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 2248 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN229_$LT$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5.._..$LT$impl$u20$serde..de..Deserialize$u20$for$u20$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5..VoteState0_23_5$GT$..deserialize..__Visitor$u20$as$u20$serde..de..Visitor$GT$9visit_seq17h82eaf761022c2655E Stack offset of 5752 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 1656 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
```

It is default using version `1.15.2` for `solana-program`.

When I force change the version to `1.14.16` I get a different error:

```
$ anchor test

Is initialized!:
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions
  at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5792:13)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5751:20)
  at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:318:21)
  at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:149:14)
  at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by running

```
anchor test --skip-local-validator
```

You must be running a local validator on a different window with:

```
solana-test-validator
```